# How many keyed in items must be checked to assume all remaining items were keyed in correctly?

Tags: probability

If I am keying in test responses which may be numbers 1-4 on a 344 item test, how many items must I check to be at least 99.9% sure that the remainder of the items were entered correclty?

Answer (score 0):

You have not actually specified a probability model. Without some probability model you cannot actually ask what is the probability of any event.

The most immediate assumption is that a worker has a probability $p \in (0,1)$ of making a mistake. Each unit they complete can be modeled as a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p \in (0,1)$ of *incorrectly* entering the information. Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ be the desired level of accuracy.

Given that I know $p$, the number of incorrectly entered items follows a Binomial distribution of $\text{Binom}(n,p)$. I can easily calculate the probability of no mistakes being made.

There are two cases:

1. $p > \alpha$. Then even if you check 364 of the items, $P(X_{365} = 1) > \alpha$. So, you can never set a threshold better than what your worker can do on an individual question.
2. $p \leq \alpha$. Since each Bernoulli trial is independent if you check any of them it does not tell you about the others. Therefore, you would have to check the smallest $N$ of them such that $P(Y_N = 0) \geq \alpha$ where $Y_N \sim \text{Binom}(N,p)$. Since $p \leq \alpha$ I know that if I check $364$ I am guaranteed to have $P(X_{365} = 1) \leq \alpha$ so I will never have to check all of them.

I hope this helps. Without some kind of probability model specified it is actually not possible to ask questions about probability.

Comment: J.,Thanks for your reply, and for pointing out the deficiency in the question. The difficulty in stating the model comes from a question I had about keying in responses. Each keyed in response is a separate item, however, I questioned the initial probability of entering a response in error since there are four possible numbers that may be keyed in for each question. Does this create a higher probability of error (.75), or is it still .5?

Comment: @Joe I would model it more generally. If there are more options, intuitively I would expect that the probability of error be higher. But, it is not clear how one would quantify that without either an assumption or an estimator. If one knew the probability of error and assumed independence (which is probably reasonable) then I think this would be sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: J., Thanks for your reply.